# Write thread-safe to file in python

Tags: python

How can I write data to a file in Python thread-safe? 
I want to safe some variables to a file for every request and every hour I want to do some grouping and write it to mysql.

In Java I now put it in an Array which is cached and this is written to a file when the array is full.

How can I do this in Python? There are many concurrent requests so it has to be thread-safe.

EDIT:

We ended up using the logging module which works fine.

Comment: Do you mean "thread-safe"?

Comment: Why not just write the rows to MySQL as you go and let its concurrency handle that, then aggregate that and do the needful?

Comment: It's possible with locking and queuing and all sorts, but it's easier to just throw it at the server, aggregated it there, or in a cronjob or similar, aggregate it in the server and insert the aggregates, or pull the data back, aggregate and insert from the client side...

Comment: The `logging` module is thread-safe. You can use that to write to file from separate threads.

Comment: @JonClements Writing to mysql is what I want to prevent. This takes to much resources since it gets around 300 requests per second.

Comment: Here is another idea: put your lines into a [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), which is thread-safe. Then you can have a separate thread to  dump that queue to MySQL from time to time.

Comment: Have you tried to use queue's and then have a background process buffer through the queue? I could show an example if you like.

Comment: The pythonic way would be to do whatever you want to do, then if thread conflict turns out to be a problem, [apply one of the many threading tools provided](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We used the logging module:

```
import logging

logpath = "/tmp/log.log"
logger = logging.getLogger('log')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.FileHandler(logpath)
ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(ch)


def application(env, start_response):
   logger.info("%s %s".format("hello","world!"))
   start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
   return ["Hello!"]
```

Comment: +1 for abusing `logging` to thread-safely write lines to a file, I do this sometimes. There is some required boilerplate and understanding of how logging works, but not reinventing the wheel is nice.

Comment: this is a good use of the logging module. logging is thread-safe and has a `FileHandler` built in. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#thread-safety)

Answer (score 8):

Look at the `Queue` class, it is thread safe.

```
from Queue import Queue
writeQueue = Queue()
```

in thread

```
writeQueue.put(repr(some_object))
```

Then to dump it to a file,

```
outFile = open(path,'w')
while writeQueue.qsize():
  outFile.write(writeQueue.get())
outFile.flush()
outFile.close()
```

`Queue` will accept any python object, so if you're trying to do something other than print to a file, just store the objects from the worker threads via `Queue.put`.

If you need to split the commits across multiple invocations of the script, you'll need a way to cache partially built commits to disk.  To avoid multiple copies trying to write to the file at the same time, use the `lockfile` module, available via pip.  I usually use json to encode data for these purposes, it supports serializing strings, unicode, lists, numbers, and dicts, and is safer than pickle.

```
with lockfile.LockFile('/path/to/file.sql'):
  fin=open('/path/to/file')
  data=json.loads(fin.read())
  data.append(newdata)
  fin.close()
  fout=open('/path/to/file','w')
  fout.write(json.dumps(data))
  fout.close()
```

Note that depending on OS features, the time taken to lock and unlock the file as well as rewrite it for every request may be more than you expect.  If possible, try to just append to the file, as that will be faster.  Also, you may want to use a client/server model, where each 'request' launches a worker script which connects to a server process and forwards the data on via a network socket.  This sidesteps the need for lockfiles; depending on how much data you're talking, it may be able to hold it all in memory in the server process, or the server may need to serialize it to disk and pass it to the database that way.

WSGI server example:

```
from Queue import Queue
q=Queue()
def flushQueue():
    with open(path,'w') as f:
       while q.qsize():
           f.write(q.get())

def application(env, start_response):
   q.put("Hello World!")
   if q.qsize() > 999:
       flushQueue()
   start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
   return ["Hello!"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however how can the queue still exist on seperate requests? I though whenever a python script (or whatever scripting language) is finished it is not possible to use any objects/variables etc from a previous request?

Comment: Okay, so that depends on what exactly you mean by a request.  When the interpreter exits, everything it's using will get GCed, so there are two options to handle this.  First, is to not have the interpreter exit, if you're talking about thread safety, the assumption most people will take is that you have some sort of continuously running daemon which can preserve state between requests.  If you mean you need multiple processes (copies of the interpreter) running in parallel, and need to avoid intermingled writes, then an OS level lockfile is the solution.  I'll expand my example with that too.

Comment: With thread safety I meant intermingled writes. I'm using Linux btw. I think the time/resources for locking and unlocking a file is to big. What we did in Java was writing a string to an array in memory after every request and when the array is full a new array is created and the old is written to a file. Depending on the amount of requests we can increase/decrease the size of the array (default was 1000).

Comment: Java would have the same problem python does with the array getting GCed on JVM exit, so it had to persist between requests.  I would suggest doing the same with python, and use a queue.  If wherever the requests are generated must launch a new interpreter each time, then use a second process and pass the data over the lo interface to it.  How are the requests generated?  And what frameworks are you using?

Comment: we don't use any framework. I want to use nginx+gunicorn. I have only written single .py script files. Can you give an example code where "hello world" is put in a queue and written to a file when the queue is 1000 large?

Comment: gunicorn is a WSGI server, so I think it should be possible to persist state between requests.  An overview of what you've got so far may be beneficial.  Regardless, I'll add a simple Queue example for WSGI.

Comment: it turned out that we could just use the logging module for this job. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: should it be `from queue import Queue` instead?

Comment: No.  The original questioner used `Queue`, which was the name of the module in Python2.x, so I answered using the module name from Python2.x.  Of course, for Python3.x, the `Queue` module was renamed `queue`.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a simple writer, that uses `threading` and `Queue` and works fine with multiple threads. Pros: teoreticaly it can aссept data from multiple processes without blocking them, and write asynconiosly in other thread. Cons: additional thread for writing consumes resourses; in CPython `threading` doesn't give real multithreading.

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread

class SafeWriter:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.filewriter = open(*args)
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.finished = False
        Thread(name = "SafeWriter", target=self.internal_writer).start()  
    
    def write(self, data):
        self.queue.put(data)
    
    def internal_writer(self):
        while not self.finished:
            try:
                data = self.queue.get(True, 1)
            except Empty:
                continue    
            self.filewriter.write(data)
            self.queue.task_done()
    
    def close(self):
        self.queue.join()
        self.finished = True
        self.filewriter.close()
                    
#use it like ordinary open like this:
w = SafeWriter("filename", "w")
w.write("can be used among multiple threads")
w.close() #it is really important to close or the program would not end
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to Thread-Safe Write to File**

Writing to a file can be made thread-safe by using a mutual exclusion (mutex) lock.

Any code that opens and writes to the file, or appends to the file can be treated as a critical section of code subject to race conditions.

This code can be protected from race conditions by requiring that the accessing thread first acquire a mutex lock before executing the critical section.

A mutex lock can only be acquired by one thread at a time, and once acquired prevents any other thread acquiring it until the lock is released.

This means that only a single thread will be able to write to the file at a time, making writing to file thread safe.

This can be achieved using the threading.Lock class.

First, a lock can be created and shared among all code that needs to access the same file.
...

## create a lock

```
lock = threading.Lock()
```

Once created, a thread can then acquire the lock before writing to file by calling the acquire() function. Once writing to the file is finished, the lock can be released by calling the release() function.

For example:
...

```
# acquire the lock
lock.acquire()
# open file for appending
with open('path/to/file.txt', 'a') as file:
    # write text to data
    file.write('Test')
# release the lock
lock.release()
```

Like opening the file, the context manager interface can be used to ensure that the lock is always released after the block enclosed code is exited.

For example:
...

```
# acquire the lock
with lock:
    # open file for appending
    with open('path/to/file.txt', 'a') as file:
        # write text to data
        file.write('Test')
```

If a thread attempts to acquire the lock while it has already been acquired, then it must block or wait until the lock is released. This waiting is performed automatically by the thread when attempting to acquire the lock, no additional code is required.